# Problem with plotting multiple curves using fitacis in plantecophys package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot multiple ACi curves in R using the 'plantecophys' package. I need the curves to be color coded by the treatment the plants received. I have done this before with a different dataset, but it is not working for my current one and I am not sure why.

The error I keep receiving is:
`Error: To colour curves by id, fit with id argument (see ?fitacis)`.

This is due `fitacis()` not recognizing the specification of the id when fitting the curves. I have changed the data used for id to a factor, which is needed to call the id. I have tried a lot of workarounds, but nothing has worked and I would like an extra set of eyes.

The code is as follows:

```
#Make Treatment.label a factor
t.datanew$Treatment.label <- as.factor(t.datanew$Treatment.label)
my.fits <- fitacis(t.datanew,group="Curve", method="bilinear",id ="Treatment.label")

#plot all fits on one graph 
palette(rainbow(2))
plot(my.fits,how="oneplot",colour_by_id = TRUE,id_legend = TRUE)
```

The treatment levels are "Regular watering" and "Overwatering".